# Opencart htacces rewrite (redirect) for news

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I need create rewrite (redirect) for my opencart News.
Example:

```
Mysite/about_us -> Mysite/content/about_us
```

**Or**

```
Mysite/delivery -> Mysite/content/delivery
```

only for News opencart.

How it to do in htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO `oc_url_alias`(`query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('about_us', 'content/about_us');

INSERT INTO `oc_url_alias`(`query`, `keyword`) VALUES ('delivery', 'content/delivery');

Comment: i don't have a page with link - /content/about_us... i have about_us

Comment: so difficult change words ?

Comment: INSERT INTO oc_url_alias(query, keyword) VALUES ('content/about_us', 'about_us');

Comment: where you make this? go to phpadmin and make sql